# WPF DataGrid Operations

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datamodel

I'm currently working on a WPF project under VS2010 where I need to make some CRUD operations directly using a datagird, so I've found it easier to work on Binding WPF Controls to an Entity Data Model which allows a lot of additional features that made my work easier.
so I've followed this tutorial [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465159(VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465159%28VS.100%29.aspx)
and everything is working fine for me .
But the problem that I'm now facing is how to make Insert/Delete Operations using the same method. I've tried to google this problem a lot but I couldn't find the right answers, so I come to you guys hoping to find some help.